# Multiple Concat calls followed by a Distinct vs multiple Union calls

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, merge, distinct

I have the current piece of code merging multiple lists of users to get all the distinct ids. I figure its faster to use `Concat` multiple times and call `Distinct` once rather than calling `Union` multiple times which would do a distinct every time, but I can't find any documentation on this. Would it be better to call `Union` rather than `Concat` here?

```
var ids = users.Where(x => x.StartDate <= currentDate))
    .Concat(archive)
    .Concat(employees.Where(x => x.InsertDate <= currentDate))
    .Concat(clients.Where(x => x.StartDate <= currentDate))
    .Concat(userRelations.Where(x => x.StartDate <= currentDate))
    .Select(x => x.UserId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Race your horses?

Comment: I think your analysis is correct. Your code constructs a big stream of values and then feeds it into a single set, whereas multiple calls to `Union` will construct multiple sets, which is a large waste of resources. The chained `Concat` calls shouldn't be a problem either, so long as you're on a newish .NET version -- anything old will end up in large function call chains to get the next element. But, benchmark to be sure. [Source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Concat.cs,9c0a66e386e37265)

Comment: @AmjadSaab I don't think that other question is related to this one

Comment: @canton7 Thanks! Although looking at [the sources for the union call](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Union.cs) I can see it wouldn't create a new set for every collection.

Comment: Aha, I missed that indeed